# Changing the format of an input date with AngularJs not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Well, I want to show an *input date field* but with the format changed.

I mean, the default format is: `yyyy-MM-dd (2015-11-20)`, but I want it: `(11-20-2015)`.

There's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7mvaosL/150/) I found with `momentjs` (without angular) and works exactly as I want.

Working with AngularJs, I have done too with a directive, but with a *span field* (and works). But if I do with an input date, it doesn't works.

This is the **html**:

```
<body ng-app="docsTimeDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  Current date is: <span my-current-time="format"></span><hr/>
  <input type="date" ng-model="myDate.value" my-current-time="format">
</div>
</body>
```

And the **Js**:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsTimeDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.format = 'MM/dd/yyyy';
    $scope.myDate = {
      value: new Date()
    };
  }])
  .directive('myCurrentTime', ['$interval', 'dateFilter', function($interval, dateFilter) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      var format,
          timeoutId;

      function updateTime() {
        element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
        console.log(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
      }

      scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
        format = value;
        updateTime();
      });

      element.on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel(timeoutId);
      });

      // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
      timeoutId = $interval(function() {
        updateTime(); // update DOM
      }, 1000);
    }

    return {
      link: link
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e5WJ38Qc2Zl1ii6xYzKR?p=preview). Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have solved my issue in 2 ways:

**1) With MomentJs**

```
attrs.$set('myCurrentDate', momentFilter(date, format));
```

and then

```
.filter('moment', function () {
    return function (date, formated) {
        moment.locale('es');
        var momented = moment(date).format(formated);
        return momented;
    };
});
```

[See the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VJmgyos5YieoCptQr97t?p=preview)

---

**2) With Javascript native Date object**

```
attrs.$set('myCurrentDate', dateFilter(date, format));
```

[See the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SgRMbrFIpkuKBoQCJWd3?p=preview)

---

But in both cases, with the help of css:

```
input:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 3px;
    content: attr(my-current-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}
```

PS: Note the difference between the definition of the variable *$scope.format* in both cases.

---

**EDIT:**

But if we don't want complications, we can use the excellent [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) from AngularUI. It has a lot of features.

And this take me to a **3rd way** for solving my issue: [See the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ae3t3GAcLfu3V9htGms1?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

This is because [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) will not apply to an `<input />` element. You'll need [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead.

You can do a very basic check to cover both cases. Observe the following (untested)...

```
element[0].value !== undefined ? element.val(/*...*/) : element.text(/*...*/)
```

Furthermore per discussion, keep in mind the [total lack of cross browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) for `type="date"`. Perhaps finding an off the shelf datepicker could be in your best interest here - likely resolving your format restriction difficulties as well.

Comment: Ok, I tried it with `element.val(dateFilter(new Date(), format));` and throws: **`The specified value "11/20/2015" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"`**

Comment: with an input `type="date"` - it does need to be in this format. Have you confirmed the returned value of your date that `dateFilter` returns? [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etpo7L8d/) that shows a date input working in its simplest form

Comment: Have you see the plunkr? In the `span` field returns the date as I want.

Comment: Also that first fiddle you provided - moment is doing some custom work there. If you inspect that datepicker you'll see the appropriate value as such `value="2015-11-20"`. You'll be looking into some custom AngularJS work to get that `<input>` to look different

Comment: @robe007 give [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/Vq65z/13/) a look for formatting

Comment: I have see in the fiddle i provided, and there is an atrr called `data-date`. This is a custom or an official attr?

Comment: that's definitely custom as indicated by `data-` [ref: ("data dash")](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95733/discussion-between-robe007-and-scniro).