# AngularJS directive wrapping TimePicki

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to wrap [TimePicki](http://senthilraj.github.io/TimePicki/index.html) in an AngularJS directive.

I cannot figure out a way to initialise the `options.start_time` option from the value currently held within `ngModel`.

If I use a watcher, it's too late as the timepicker has already been initialised, and if I use `ctrl.$modelValue`, it's too early as the value is set to null when the directive is rendered.

My only other option (that I know of) is a watcher, but I don't want to initialise the timepicker every time the value of `ngModel` changes, as we'd end up with a mess - and `ngModel`'s value might not change until the user wishes to select a new time.

Shown below is the code I currently have for the directive.

```js
(function () {
 "use strict";

 angular.module("timePicker", [])
  .directive('timepicker', ["$parse", function ($parse) {
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<input type="text" />',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
     var ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

     var options = {
      on_change: function (time) {
       scope.$apply(function (scope) {
        ngModel.assign(scope, moment(time.value, "hh:mm A"));
       });
      }
     }

     ctrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
      if (!angular.isDefined(value)) { return null; }

      return value.format("hh:mm A");
     });

     ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
      return moment(value, "hh:mm A");
     });

     $(element).timepicki(options);

    }
   };
  }]);

}());
```

```html
<input id="txtTime" 
    type="text" 
    ng-model="eventEdit.event.time" 
    name="timepicker" 
    class="time_element" 
    readonly="readonly"
    timepicker />
```

Comment: Maybe, something like this  》[https://stackoverflow.com/q/33832849/2954267](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33832849/2954267)

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I'm trying to wrap timepicki in an angular directive as I've done before, but nothing happens